# Nested query is not working for Entity Framework to bind repeater control

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-6

```
string sql = string.Format(
    @"SELECT M.ManufacturerID
            ,M.DeviceCode
            ,M.DeviceName
            ,M.Repertoire,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Catalogue AS [C] WHERE(([C].ManufacturerID = [M].ManufacturerID) AND ([C].DeviceCode = [M].DeviceCode) AND ([C].VendorID = [V].VendorID)))  [LotsCount]
            FROM Manufacturers AS [M]
            LEFT JOIN Vendors AS [V] ON [V].ManufacturerID = M.ManufacturerID
            WHERE (([V].VendorID LIKE ‘%V0%’)  AND ([M].Enabled = 1))
            ORDER BY [M].DeviceCode")

return  ctx.Manufacturers.SqlQuery(sql).ToList();
```

The return values going to bind repeater control but here `[LotsCount]` is not bound to my repeater

```
<itemtemplate>
```

at

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="LST_LotsCount" Text='<%# Eval("LotsCount") %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with the return value of the query..?

Comment: You're creating `Manufacturer` objects and I don't think `LotsCount` is a `Manufacturer` property. Or if it is, it's not populated by the query. First step in analyzing this is to store `ctx.Manufacturers.SqlQuery(sql).ToList();` in a variable and return the variable, so you can put a break point on the return statement and check what's returned.

Comment: It returns the list of values, but there LotsCount is an Extra Alias column name, not a column of manufacturer table. Here the extra column name not bonded to my repeater control Why?

Comment: Do the returned `Manufacturer`s really have the expected `LotsCount` values? If `LotsCount` is a not-mapped property in `Manufacturer` it won't be populated by your query.